# Having problems of skipping loops after scanf

Tags: c, for-loop, scanf, codeblocks

I am in my first year of uni, studying c. I am doing one of my assignment but having problems with one of the loop just skipping. I am using Codeblocks with the GNU GCC compiler. Please ignore option 2, 3, 4.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int num, i, numscr;
    float grade[2021];
    int id[2021];
    int opt;
    float avg[2021];
    float sum=0.0;
    do {
        printf("\nOption 1: Enter student's info\n");
        printf("Option 2: Print out student's info\n");
        printf("Option 3: Find the student with the lowest and highest grade\n");
        printf("Option 4: Exit\n");
        printf("Enter option: ");
        scanf("%d", &opt);
        if(opt==1)
        {
            printf("\n\tEnter the amount of student (Amount>=2): ");
            scanf("%d", &num);
            printf("\tEnter the amount of subject: ");
            scanf("%d",&numscr);
            for(i=0; i<num; i++)
            {
                printf("\n\tEnter student's id: ");
                scanf("%d", &id[i]);
                for(i=1; i<=numscr; i++)
                {
                    printf("\tEnter point of subject %d: " ,i);
                    scanf("%f", &grade[i]); /*The loop skips here.
                    After entering the grade for each subject,
                    it just skips whatever student's id and subject's point there are left.
                    I think the problem is with the sum+=grade[I]; but I don't know why*/
                    sum+= grade[i];
                }
            }
            avg[i]=sum/numscr;
        }
    } while(opt>0 && opt<=3)
    return 0;
}
```

Sorry if the code doesn't look great, I forgot to format it until now. If anyone can help then I really appreciate it, I've been racking my head for the entirety of the afternoon now.

Comment: "I forgot to format it until now." Why not format now?

Comment: I did. It looked even worse then

Comment: You have nested loops that both use `i` for control.

Comment: Always check the return value of `scanf()`

Answer (score 0):

You used `i` for both loops of `for(i=0; i<num; i++)` and `for(i=1; i<=numscr; i++)`. This means that the inner loop will use `i` and affect the outer loop.

Use another variable (for example, `j`) for the inner loop to fix.

Also it looks like you forgot to initialize `sum` before calculating the average for each query.

Comment: Thank you @MikeCAT , replacing i with a different digit definitely did the trick. By initializing sum , do you mean adding sum=0.0; at the top of the for(i=0; i<num; i++) loop so that the value of sum+=grade[i]; can reset?. Sorry to bother, English isn't my mother tounge

Comment: @SpottedPredator Ah, yes. Actually the statement `avg[i]=sum/numscr;` is placed after the loop `for(i=0; i<num; i++)` and the average is not for each students but for all students!